# Assigning default drive permissions

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, permissions, windows-server-2012

Been looking around everywhere but can't seem to find the answer to this - hopefully someone can assist.

Scenario: I have a Windows 2012 R2 server that has a C: drive only. Someone wants to add in a D: and E: drive - is there is a way of assigning default NTFS drive permissions on the newly created drive automatically?

So, for example when they add the drive then the permissions are automatically assigned to SYSTEM, Authenticated Users and maybe another group on the ROOT of D: drive. I have a feeling there might be a key in the registry that can do this but am stuck thus far.

Comment: Windows will set the default permissions upon creation of the volume. Are you asking how set a different set of permissions as the default?

Comment: Yes that's what I am asking